# Woocommerce product changes are revert automatically to first revision

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce shop. For few products, when I edit them, they revert to their first revision automatically after about ~4-20 min of the edit.

I checked the database and realized that this changes are made by a user of `0` id (**post_author of posts table = 0**) and the rest of product info like main picture or gallery images remain unchanged. I mean only posts table gets new record of revision of post_author=0.

I made a new role named *Site Admin* and has post edit permission. The *Reverting* products are made and edited by that role and get revert automatically **BUT** if I edit posts with Administrator role, they remain **unchanged**.

I don't know if it is a normal/hidden behavior of WordPress or not or what schedule should I check or if I missed a setting or permission to give to the Site Admin role.